# Запятую нужно ставить?

Tags: запятые, союзы, как

Скажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая?

*Рискуя своей жизнью, герой спас возлюбленную из плена, а после того(,) как Петра осудили за предательство, девушка смогла убедить императрицу в его невиновности.*

Либо же запятую нужно ставить перед союзом "после того"?

Answer (score 1):

Правильно:

*Рискуя своей жизнью, герой спас возлюбленную из плена, **а после того как Петра осудили за предательство,** девушка смогла убедить императрицу в его невиновности.*

Расчленение союза в общем случае **факультативное**, поэтому надо сделать выбор.

В этом предложении  **лучше не выделять** местоименную часть. Оно **распространенное**, поэтому такая детализация смысла и лишние запятые нежелательны. В **препозиции** придаточного предложения союз чаще не расчленяется, запятая ставится **один раз** (после придаточного).

**[Розенталь, пункт 1(2) и 2](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=138#pp138)**

***После того как** началась война и завод перешёл на оборонные заказы, остановка цехов на сутки, естественно, оказалась невозможной* (Поп.).

Comment: нужно ли ставить запятую после союза а в данном примере ?

Comment: Не нужно. Мы не можем переставить придаточное для проверки, поэтому союз А относится ко всему СПП.